# LibGDX font issues

Tags: android, libgdx

I've started creating a small project for the store with LibGDX. So far I only tested on PC, and everything went well. I'm using the `gdx-smart-font` library for font rendering. The fonts are looking good on a clean start:

[image: the way it looks on a clean start]

But if I exit from the app (ex.: via the back button, or the home button), and it still remains in the memory, then if I launch the app again, the whole font set is messed up:

[image]

Currently I have a `Settings` class, which loads the fonts, and creating a skin for the `TextButtonStyle`s and `LabelStyle`s, and I only have code in the `Screen`s `show`, `resize` and `render` function.

Comment: This might be due to context loss. Try reloading the fonts when you detect a user relaunching the app.

Comment: I tried reloading the resources AND reinstating the layout in the `resume` function, but still the same error :(

Comment: @StrongJoshua ahh.. you were right.. I disposed the previous textures in the resume, not in the pause, and that was what caused my problem.. Post an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to either a context loss or simply you disposing your textures, without recreating them at the proper time (as you pointed out).